# how to get extension name of an uploaded image file from Django request.data

Tags: python, django, image, opencv

UPDATE on rephrased question:

I am using Django and have implemented a REST API image file post.

I obtain the image object like this:

```
  image_obj = request.data['image']
```

How do I get the extension name ? For example, if the file is image.jpg, I want to get "jpg" as the extension name.

---

Below was my original question (You can ignore as the goal is above):

Is there a way to determine the type of image like jpg, jpeg, png, etc so that I can decode it back to the same format ?

For example, here I have a http post on an image file that creates an OpenCVv object with imdecode, and reformats the object with imencode.

```
  image_obj = request.data['image']

  im_cv = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(image_obj.read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

  ... do something like crop, detection, etc

  ret, buf_im_cv = cv2.imencode( '.png', im_cv ) # in this case I have to specify png, what if its jpg, etc
```

Comment: `.png`, `.jpg`, etc. are image compression formats, and once the image is decoded, the OpenCV matrix only stores the RGB data and the dimensions of the image matrix. So you may need to cache the image format to another variable before decoding.

Comment: imdecode does not need to know the compression type, it will look at the data header to decide which compression technique has to be used. If you want to re-encode the image with the same codec, you'll probably have to evaluate the image header (or maybe the http header??) yourself.

Answer (score 4):

This method of string objects -***split***- will help you:

```
ext = image_obj.name.split('.')[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass image name as hidden field in the form and use it to parse file extension.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def employee_test(request):
    """
    description: employee_management_test
    parameters:   
      - name: image
        type: file
        required: true
        location: form                               
    """   
    image_obj = request.data['image']
    imagename = request.data['imagename']
    # Also handle the case of file not having extension
    extension = imagename[imagename.rfind("."):] 
    ...
    # Do you stuff here
    ret, buf_im_cv = cv2.imencode(extension, im_cv)
```

Comment: hi, tq, it has this error: AttributeError: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Comment: i even tried this but it has the same issue - AttributeError: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'split' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976732/how-to-get-the-extension-of-a-file-in-django. extension = u_file.split(".").lower()[-1]

Comment: You should send the filename in the request. Then you can access it using request.data['filename'] and parse it.

Comment: how do i pass filename, it actually uploads the file image binaries ? i updated the rest api param for this.

Comment: Add a hidden field in the form, which will be populated as you upload the file, pass it along with other form data.

Comment: hmm... i dont think its the right way. i think there is way to capture this from the object somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that file extension name might not exactly indicate the real encoding format of an image file, e.g. anyone can name a file `xxx.jpg` which is actually a TIFF image.

The more reliable approach would be to use existing packages, such as :

- [imghdr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html) , a built-in python package
- [magic](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/) , a third-party package that relies on [`libmagic`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/magic_getflags.3.html) at OS level, many of popular OS distros should already include this library.

Both of the packages above work in similar way by extracting beginning portion of a file to check the image encoding format. `magic` is relatively more reliable than `magic` in my experience, but both are better than extracting the extension from file name.